# Question about the second order linear elliptic PDE on closed manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Recently I see a question
[linear second order PDE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346354/simple-existence-and-uniqueness-for-second-order-and-linear-elliptic-pde)

in which user Pedro post a reference in Gilbarg's book, which said that the solvability of the linear PDE
$$
\Delta u +B^{i}(x)u_{i}+C(x)u=f
$$
is equal to the poisson equation
$$
\Delta u = f
$$
But it's well-known that the solvability of poisson equation on compact manifold is
$$
\int_{M} f = 0
$$
If $C<0$, for the $$
\Delta u +B^{i}(x)u_{i}+C(x)u=f
$$
we can easily have an $C^{0}$ estimate, by Calderon-Zygmund inequality we can have a $H^{2,2}$ estimate, then iterate this process I think we can get the solution but we don't need the $f$ to be $$
\int_{M} f = 0
$$
There must be something wrong, could someone help me.